# When I plot a graph in R all the characters get transformed in strange characters

Tags: r, plot, rstudio-server

Since this morning, every graph that I've generated get all the numbers and characters transformed in strange characters (like a squared zero).

After `ggplot`, I tried with `plot` and get the same error.

The reproductible example is : `plot(c(1,2,3))`. I get this graph :

[image]

I use a session connected to RStudio Server.

I tried to restart my session, to use another session (another profile without any packages), to restart RStudio Server and to restart the server. I also tried to reinstall R. I still get the same problem.

How can I solve this problem ?

Comment: Could you give me some reproducible code and data so we can help you better

Comment: The problem is the same with every graph I generate. The reproducible code therefore can be something quite simple like "plot(c(1,2,3))"

Comment: Have you tried to restart your R session?

Comment: I tried to restart my session, to use another session (another profile), to restart RStudio Server and to restart the server. I still get the same problem :/

Comment: What graphics device are you plotting to? This is almost certainly a font problem. You might have to reinstall R to fix the internal font cache (there might be other ways but I don’t know them, and as far as I know they’re not documented).

Comment: I'm plotting on a Windows computer screen. I'll try to reinstall R

Comment: I just reinstalled R, I'm still having the same problem :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My colleague finally solved the problem.

The problem was a missing libpango1.0-0 library (that was removed when upgrading a bunch of packages to their debian stretch version on a debian jessie system to have an up-to-date libgdal library so that the r-gdal package could be used).