# R plot symbols on axis not shown correctly

Tags: r, plot, character-encoding

[image: output of plot(1,1)]

Hi guys,

I have set up a new conda R-environment (on my ubuntu 20.04) and oddly, the output of the base plot function does not show symbols on the axes or axis labels but little squares with numbers instead (see attached picture).
When I use the plot function in an R-Markdown code chunk and export it as PDF, the plot is displayed correctly. However, in RStudio or when exporting the Rmd to html, the symbols appear like in the picture.

I realize this could have to do with the encoding, but don't know how to solve it. Has anyone encountered this problem before or can give me advice how to troubleshoot it?

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: Try restarting the R session, the problem might go away.

Comment: @RuiBarradas thanks, but I've tried that already. Unfortunately, the problem persists :(

Comment: Do you have a .RData file in your home directory? If so, remove it. I know I already had this problem but I don't remember how I solved it. See if [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54810065/when-i-plot-a-graph-in-r-all-the-characters-get-transformed-in-strange-character) can help.

Comment: no, I don't have a .RData file in my home directory, nor in the current working directory

Comment: Or maybe [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67207156/how-fix-character-encoding-in-r-plots).

Comment: thanks a lot @RuiBarradas , the post was actually the solution to my problem! Installing cairodevice in my r environment solved it.

Answer (score 0):

Simply adding the package r-cairodevice to my R environment solved the problem.